# Strategy to Loop Through 2D Array from Google Sheets To Create Entry for Each Date and ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheet that contains data I need to manipulate. It is essentially a list of assignments by student.  The original columns are:

`Name, ID, Assignment 1, Assignment 2, Assignment 3, Assignment 4, Date, Overall Grade`

Using existing code, I am concatenating the Assignments into a single field and creating an array with these columns:

`ID, Name, Assignments, Date, Overall Grade`

The resulting array looks like this:

```
[ [ '1234',
    'Santa Claus',
    'US History Chapter 1.1, , , ',
    Fri Nov 18 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time),
    'B+' ],
  [ '1234',
    'Santa Claus',
    'US History Chapter 2.1, US History Chapter 1.1, , ',
    Thu Nov 17 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time),
    'B' ],
 [ '12222',
    'Mary Poppins',
    'US History Chapter 8, , , ',
    Fri Nov 18 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time),
    'A' ]]
```

On a separate sheet I have a list of dates. What I want is to have a line for every single student and date combination and the assignment data if it exists. E.g. If the dates are `Nov 17, Nov 18, and Nov19` and there are 2 students with data in the list, there would be 6 total entries sorted by student then by date. For the `Assignments` column, there would only be data if there was an assignment entered for that date and that student. Otherwise it would be blank. For example:

| ID | Name | Assignments | Date | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Santa Claus | Chapter 2.1, US History Chapter 1.1 | Nov17 | B |
| 1234 | Santa Claus | US History Chapter 1.1 | Nov18 | B+ |
| 1234 | Santa Claus |  | Nov19 |  |
| 12222 | Mary Poppins |  | Nov17 |  |
| 12222 | Mary Poppins | US History Chapter 8 | Nov 18 | A |
| 12222 | Mary Poppins |  | Nov19 |  |

What I think is needed is something like this:

1. Get unique list of all student IDs from the array
2. Get list of dates from the sheet
3. Use a nested loop to go through each date and each student to create the lines. If there is a match for the assignment data, add it, if not, leave that blank.

I'm just not sure how to manipulate the array to do something like that. How would I approach this?

Comment: Does `Assignment 2`, `Assignment 3`, and `Assignment 4` have a grade? would be helpful to give sample data for the original sheet.

Comment: In order to correctly replicate and understand your current situation and your goal, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect?

Comment: I've added a sample output table that I'd like in array format. The original input is the array shown.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Although, unfortunately, I cannot know your actual array, from your showing sample array and a sample table, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
const array = [,,,]; // Please set your array.

const res = Object.entries(array.reduce((o, e) => (o[e[0]] = o[e[0]] ? [...o[e[0]], e] : [e], o), {}))
  .sort(([a], [b]) => Number(a) > Number(b) ? 1 : -1)
  .flatMap(([, v]) => v.sort((a, b) => a[3].getTime() > b[3].getTime() ? 1 : -1));

console.log(res)
```

- In this sample script, first, an object is created by checking the column "A". And, sort the array by the column "A". And, for each element, sort the column "D". And, all values are merged as a 2-dimensional array.

#### Note:

- If this sample script doesn't return your exected values, can you provide the detailed sample input values and the sample output values? By this, I would like to confirm it.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)